# Parse url with ./, ../, ../../ etc

Tags: javascript

Say I have a URL like such:

```
https://example.com/cheesey_poofs/../goo
```

How would I make it parse to something like so?

```
https://example.com/goo
```

Comment: Does replacing work for you? Such as:

var url = "https://example.com/cheesey_poofs/../goo";
var normalizedUrl = url.replaceAll("../", "");

Comment: ^ This makes no sense at all. This would leave `cheesesy_poofs` in the URL, which is incorrrect

Comment: + it also has to work with things like /../../../ etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com/cheesey_poofs/../goo');

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit long operation using string split

```js
let input = 'https://example.com/cheesey_poofs/../goo';
let input_arr = input.split('//');
let protocol = input_arr[0] + '//';
let url = input_arr[1];
let url_arr = url.split('/');
let result =  protocol + [url_arr[0], url_arr[url_arr.length-1]].join('/');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It needs to work with other types, like ./, /../, etc.

Comment: use `const` if you don't reassign the values. You can also use [.at(-1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) to get the last place instead of `[url_arr.length-1]`